# How to set "style=display:none;" using jQuery's attr method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

Following is the form with id `msform` that I want to apply style="display:none" attribute to.

```
<form id="msform" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

Also the check should be performed before adding the `"style=display:none;"` property. That is if it is already set like in above code it should not set again.

But if it's not set then it should.

How should I achieve this? Please help me.

Comment: *why are you removing the style completely?* (mentioned in comment below). I would have to see the rest of your code/HTML, but changing styles is normally a better option than doing that. If you want to provide more detail you may get a more useful answer :)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Why not just use `$('#msform').hide()`? Behind the scene jQuery's `hide` and `show` just set `display: none` or `display: block`.

`hide()` will not change the style if already hidden.

based on the comment below, you are removing all style with `removeAttr("style")`, in which case call `hide()` immediately after that.

e.g.

```
$("#msform").removeAttr("style").hide();
```

The reverse of this is of course `show()` as in

```
$("#msform").show();
```

Or, more interestingly, `toggle()`, which effective flips between `hide()` and `show()` based on the current state.

Comment: I tried to use that but later on I'm having a code to remove style attribute $("#msform").removeAttr("style"); so I want to set style="display:none;". How to do it?

Comment: Again... just call `hide()` after the `removeAttr("style")`

Comment: is there any way to use .hide() with .before(),
Basically i want to add an hidden element    -- http://jsfiddle.net/95jeL9xc/2/

Answer (score 52):

As an alternative to `hide()` mentioned in other answers, you can use `css()` to set the `display` value explicitly:

```
$("#msform").css("display","none")
```

Comment: Using 21 characters instead of the 6 of "hide()" would be my only objection (this is for a web page after all) :)

Comment: yeah i get that you're trying to provide an alternative, but if you got beat to a much simpler answer, no real reason to most a much longer one.

Comment: @jmore009 Idk, this, in a sense, more literally answers the original question. Is using `hide` and `show` more conventional, and probably a better route? Yes, imo. But if you literally want to change the string attached to `display`, this is howie doit. /shrug

Answer (score 10):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var display =  $("#msform").css("display");
    if(display!="none")
    {
        $("#msform").attr("style", "display:none");
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `hide` and `show` functions of jquery. [Examples](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)

In your case just set `$('#msform').hide()` or `$('#msform').show()`

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment we are removing one property from style attribute.

Here this was not affect, but when more property are used within the style it helpful.

```
$('#msform').css('display', '')
```

After this we use

```
$("#msform").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use: `$("#msform").hide()`. This sets the element to `display: none`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery [attr() method](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to achieve the setting of teh attribute and the method [removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) to delete the attribute for your element msform
As seen in the code

```
$('#msform').attr('style', 'display:none;');


$('#msform').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code for it :

```
$('#msform').fadeOut(50);

$('#msform').fadeIn(50);
```